# Remove Some array elements based on a condition and update size of array as one more filed in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following collection

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408"),
    "myarray": [
      {
        "point": 5,
        "userId": "570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"
      },
      {
        "point": 2,
        "userId": "613ca5e48dbe673802c2d521"
      },
      {
        "point": 4,
        "userId": "570ca5e48dbe673802c2d045"
      },
      {
        "point": 4,
        "userId": "570ca5e48dbe473802c2d035"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have a collection like above and I want to remove some objects inside array based on userID condition and after removing I have to update one field in mongo with size of array

I'm trying with the below query where removing array elements is working as excepted but array size is not updating properly

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408")
},
{
  $pull: {
    "myarray": {
      userId: {
        $in: [
          "570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035",
          "613ca5e48dbe673802c2d521"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "$set": {
    profilecount: {
      $size: "$myarray"
    }
  }
})
```

to see result of query please click this link and run query https://mongoplayground.net/p/FtMk7ymacr3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using an update with a pipeline:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408")
},
[{
    $set: {
      "myarray": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$myarray",
          cond: {
            $not: {
              $in: [
                "$$this.userId",
                ["570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035", "613ca5e48dbe673802c2d521"]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$set: {profilecount: {$size: "$myarray"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/18NI11zPvaC)